# The getExternalFilesDirs method doesn't returns external writable SD path in 4.4.+

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I'm trying to get writable directory of my SD which is mounted and accesible from other apps like file explorers. I use Android 4.4.2 on Hannspree tablet.

I've tryed to plug sdcard with the device off and with the device on

The method:

```
File[] list = ctx.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
```

It only returns the external (internal) memory file `(list.length == 1)`:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.packet.name/files/
```

I've already set the necessary permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If read the `/proc/mounts` file I get two mounted directories

```
/mnt/sdcard -> READONLY false -> INTERNAL true 
/mnt/sd-ext -> READONLY false -> INTERNAL false
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `I've already tryed to plug sdcard on switched on dispositive and with the switched off dispositive`. I've no idea where you are talking about. What did you do? For the rest i can confirm that i investigated five 4.4 devices obtaining the same results as yours. Moreover on all the devices my apps could not write to the SD card. Mostly the camera app could deposit pictures on SD card though. One device came with a file explorer that could write on SD card and usb sticks.

Comment: Sory for my english :p.  I wanted to say that I 've tried to insert the card  with the device on and off. In my case, I can write to SD card with camera and other APPS like "ES File Explorer". However in Asus Transformer PAD with 4.4.2 works fine

Comment: How have you solved this problem with this kind of devices?

Comment: Let the user indicate the directory where the SD card is mounted. Add a file/directory chooser. It is always or under /mnt or under /storage.

Comment: Then I will have to hardcode path like this?: mountpointselected/Android/data/com.packet.name/files/

Comment: Well it would be more like `selectedDir +"/Android/data/com.packet.name/files"`. Then check if it exists and if not you can mkdir() the files subdir. I don't know if it is advisable to mkdirs() the whole path if it does not exist. And check all with File.canWrite() too.

Comment: I am trying the same method to get list of paths for mounted devices but when I write statement to make a call to the method it gets underlined in RED with message "The method getExternalFilesDirs(null) is undefined for the type DashboardActivity". Application I am trying to use this method in has min sdk version 16 and targeted sdk version 19. I have verified all the required SDK tools for API level 19 using Android SDK Manager and it shows the complete package installed. Can anybody please help what possibly can go wrong with a call to method getExternalFilesDirs(null). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You Need to do something like this Hope it will help you

```
private getDir(File path)
{
    if (dir.exists()) {
    File[] files = dirPath.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
    File folder = files[i];
    if (folder.isDirectory()) {
        Log.d("Directory Name : " , ""+folder.getName());
        Log.d("Writeable or not : " , ""+folder.canWrite());
        getDir(folder);

    } else {
       //Do what you want with files..
    }
 }
}
```